# Quicksort algorithm only works with lists with small numbers. Why?

Tags: haskell, quicksort

I have added two helping functions to split the lists and to add tupples.
The output with two different lists as input shows my problem.

*Main> quicksort [367,324,675,238,1237,345,12,45,1,434,2,1,33,43]
[1,1,2,12,33,43,45,238,324,345,367,434,675,1237]                - It works

*Main> quicksort [3687,324,675,238,1237,345,12,45,1,434,2,1,33,43]
[3687,324,675,238,1237,345,12,45,1,434,2,1,33,43] - doesn't work

Down below is the code:

```
    splitBy :: Int -> [Int] -> ([Int],[Int])

    splitBy n y = ([x|x <- y,x > n],[x|x <- y, x<=n]) 
    addi :: ([a],[a]) -> ([a],[a]) -> ([a],[a])
    addi ([],[]) ([],[]) = ([],[])
    addi (x,y) (w,z) =  (x++w,y++z)

    splitBy' :: Int -> [Int] -> ([Int],[Int])

    splitBy' _ [] = ([],[])
    splitBy' n (y:ys) =  addi (q,d) (splitBy' n ys)
        where q = if y > n then [] else [y]
            d = if y <= n then [] else [y]
    addi' :: ([a],[a]) -> [a]
    addi' ([],[]) = []
    addi' (x,z) = x++z
    quicksort :: [Int] -> [Int]
    quicksort [] = []
    quicksort (x:xs) 
        | (l1 /= []    ) && (l2 /= []) = addi'(quicksort l1', quicksort l2')
        | l1 == [] = addi' (l1, quicksort l2)
        | l2 == [] = addi' (l1,l2)
            where
                (l1,l2) = splitBy' x (x:xs)
                (l1',l2') =  (addi'(splitBy' (x-1) l1),addi' (splitBy' (x+1) l2))
```

Comment: You realise that (not-degeneracy-robust, as yours seems to be as well) quicksort can just be written `quicksort (x:xs) = quicksort (filter (<x) xs) ++ [x] ++ quicksort (filter (>=x) xs)`? If yes, then it wouldn't hurt to explain briefly what the idea behind your approach is.

Comment: Your guards `| l1 == [] = addi' (l1, quicksort l2) | l2 == [] = addi' (l1,l2)` mean that if `l2` is ever empty, but `l1` isn't (which is going to happen) you just stop sorting. Also, `addi' (x,y)` is just `x ++ y`, the second split is unnecessary, and of course `[] ++ x` = `x ++ []` = `x`, so for all those cases where you compare against empty lists you can greatly simplify your function.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the numbers being "small". For example, `quicksort [13,8,11,7,12,9,3,6,1,10,2,1,4,5]` gives `[13,8,11,7,12,9,3,6,1,10,2,1,4,5]` (I just replaced the "big" numbers in your example list with "small" ones that have the same ordering). Now: how short of a list can you make that doesn't get sorted correctly? Can you make it small enough to execute the function by hand?

Comment: Random code review comment: There is no need for your `addi'`. It does nothing else than `(++)` itself, so everywhere where you write `addi'(x,y)` just write `x ++ y`.

Answer (score 9):

When debugging such code, `QuickCheck` is an amazingly helpful tool.

I put your code into `Test.hs`, loaded it in `ghci` and then ran this:

```
*Test> import Test.QuickCheck
*Test Test.QuickCheck> quickCheck $ \xs -> quicksort xs == Data.List.sort xs
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 8 tests and 5 shrinks):    
[1,0]
*Test Test.QuickCheck> quicksort [1,0]
[1,0]
```

Now you have a very small input (`[1,0]`) to look at and trace through your code:

```
  quicksort (1::0::[]) -- has (l1,l2) = splitBy' 1 [1,0] = ([1,0],[])
= addi' ([1,0], [])       -- because  `l2 == []`
= [1,0] ++ []
= [1,0]
```

Presumably you had a different behavior of either `splitBy'` or your checks in `quicksort` in mind. Check where this execution differs from your intention, and you will find how to fix your code.